# Swift NavigationController push method request doesn't work from PopUp view

Tags: swift, popup, segue

1. The new PopUp `ViewController` is presented `.overCurrentContext`
2. There are 2 buttons with navigation for 2 other views from PopUp view.
3. A simple action such as `print` goes well, but when I try to segue programmatically (from `xib` file, `popUpViewController`) nothing happens.

   ```
   let vc = RegisterEmailViewController.instantiate()
   vc.coordinator = self
   navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)
   ```

Goes well from any other view.
What could be wrong?

PopUpViewController code:

```
//  Created by ᴀʟᴇxᴀɴᴅʀ ᴢʜᴇʟɪᴇᴢɴɪᴀᴋ on 23.12.2019.
//  Copyright © 2019 ᴀʟᴇxᴀɴᴅʀ ᴢʜᴇʟɪᴇᴢɴɪᴀᴋ. All rights reserved.

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, Storyboarded {
    weak var coordinator: MyCoordinator?

    @IBAction func dismissPopUp(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func buttonEmail(_ sender: Any) {
        let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "EmailViewController") as? EmailViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
    }

    @IBAction func buttonPhone(_ sender: Any) {
        let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PhoneViewController") as? PhoneViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

}
```

Comment: Does your popUp `ViewController` embed in with `UINavigationController`? Does console give you any warnings when you trying to push new vc?

Comment: @vpoltave Yes, it is embedded with UINavigationController? of Coordinator.
No warnings, no errors. Nothing. It seems it doesn't call methods/views outside the popup view.

Comment: Can you add more code, which is associated with problem, with creating navigation and your popUp vc please?

Comment: `navigationController` is optional property of `UIViewController`, `navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)` this shouldn't even compile. Can you print it's value inside your `IBAction`?

Comment: And how you presenting this initial `ViewController`? Add code if possible please too

Comment: ok, you can put another instantiateViewController method, but it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

There is `MyCoordinator` which inits all navigations and doesn't let me simply to segue/navigate by my own.

```
var childCoordinators = [Coordinator]()
var navigationController: UINavigationController

init(navigationController: UINavigationController) {
    self.navigationController = navigationController
}
```

Therefore, a reference to the controller solved the issue. It is possible to navigate aside, until new subViews, separate views are called.

Code that worked in this case:

```
    let vc = RegisterEmailViewController.instantiate()
    vc.coordinator = self
    navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)
```

Conclusion. Simple there are two ways:

1. To delete all dependencies and other methods which use
   `UINavigationController`
2. To declare only by new methods for global usage.